# C++ set_difference method not working as expected

Tags: c++, stl, set-difference

I'm trying to find the difference of these 2 sets {1,2,3,4,5,6} and 
{1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2} . The `missing` vector should contain just {5} but it contains {2,4,5} . What am I doing wrong here ?

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    vector<int> missing;
    vector<int> range(A.size());
    for(int i=1; i<= A.size(); i++) range[i-1] = i;

    set_difference(range.begin(), range.end(), A.begin(), A.end(), std::inserter(missing, missing.end()));
    return missing[0]; // Missing contains 2,4,5 where as it should had contain just 5
}

int main(){
    vector<int> A = {1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2};
    cout << solution(A);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `set_difference` requires sorted ranges as input. `{1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2}` is not sorted (at least not in accordance to default comparator).

Answer (score -1):

The 2nd argument to **std::inserter** method should be **missing.begin()** not **missing.end()**.

```
std::sort(A.begin(),A.end());

set_difference(range.begin(), range.end(), A.begin(), A.end(), std::inserter(missing, missing.begin()));
```

Comment: At that point `missing.begin() == missing.end()`. It's the sort of `A` that fixes it

Comment: Yah missing.begin() change does not fix it only sorting does.

Comment: If you observe my reply carefully, i have added sort statement also.